# Let's Encrypt on Android gives java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found

Tags: android, certificate, root, lets-encrypt

Hi have setup a small serve, generated a free certificate from Let's encrypt and configured Nginx to use that certificate (fullchain.pem and privkey.pem)

However, when I attempt to make a call from my Android app (with OkHttp3)
I get this error

```
java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found
```

Is Let's encrypt root certificate not trusted by the Android cert trust store? Or did I miss something when setting up nginx?
What is a work around for this If i still want to use Let's encrypt certificates?

Comment: "Is Let's encrypt root certificate not trusted by the Android cert trust store?" -- it will depend in part on the version of Android. Older devices are more likely to have issues. "Or did I miss something when setting up nginx?" -- test with a regular Web browser and see if the browser complains. "What is a work around for this" -- set up certificate pinning in OkHttp, pinning to the Let's Encrypt root certificate.

Comment: Using a regular android browser works just fine.Looks like it is more an issue with JDK trust store :/

Comment: did you find a solution for this ? I have the same problem

Comment: Any updates on the issue? I am facing the same problem too!

Comment: I think I had gave up and manually imported my certificate in the trust store (just for testing)

Comment: same issue here, did you solve it ?

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure it's useful but, the `/etc/letsencrypt/live/<your domain>/README` file says:

> This directory contains your keys and certificates.
>
> `privkey.pem`  : the private key for your certificate.
>
> `fullchain.pem`: the certificate file used in most server software.
>
> `chain.pem`    : used for OCSP stapling in Nginx >=1.3.7.
>
> `cert.pem`  : will break many server configurations, and should not be used
>                    without reading further documentation (see link below).
>
> We recommend not moving these files. For more information, see the
>   Certbot User Guide at
>   https://certbot.eff.org/docs/using.html#where-are-my-certificates.

So maybe you should be using `chain.pem`?

On the other hand, for those not even using Nginx, **I was getting the same error from Android because I mistakenly used `chain.pem` instead of `fullchain.pem`.**  One of the solutions for Android apps require you send the whole chain of certificates (i.e.: `fullchain.pem`), as explained here:

https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html#CommonHostnameProbs

> There are two approaches to solve this issue:
>
> - Configure the server to include the intermediate CA in the server
>     chain. Most CAs provide documentation on how to do this for all common
>     web servers. This is the only approach if you need the site to work
>     with default Android browsers at least through Android 4.2.
> - Or, treat the intermediate CA like any other unknown CA, and create a
>     TrustManager to trust it directly, as done in the previous two
>     sections.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

In let's encrypt user guide:

```
If you’re using OCSP stapling with Nginx >= 1.3.7, chain.pem should be provided as the ssl_trusted_certificate to validate OCSP responses.
```

For others who are using Apache, check your apache version.
For one of my server I set up. I was using Apache < 2.4.8. In let's encrypt user guide:

```
cert.pem contains the server certificate by itself, and chain.pem contains the additional intermediate certificate... 
Apache < 2.4.8 needs these for SSLCertificateFile and SSLCertificateChainFile, respectively.
```

So, for **SSLCertificateFile**, use *cert.pem*;
for **SSLCertificateChainFile** use *chain.pem*.

I originally using *fullchain.pem* for **SSLCertificateFile** only. it worked for most browsers, and iOS. But Android complained about it with the above error.

Separately configuring the cert and chain in Apache, all platforms work well.

Comment: I don't remember what was the problem or how I fixed but I remember it was something between the screen and the chair